# wxPython: Problems with GridBagSizer

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm new to wxpython and it seems to be very powerful tool for building up GUI, but I have a question about GridBagSizer. Could you please tell me how to adjust the size of the items that are placed inside GridBagSizer to the size of the frame they are supposed to be placed in. I attached the sample at the end: the buttons from 8 to 13 go beyond the frame, but what I want is to make the size of the buttons automatically resize to fit the frame. Any advices and suggestions are appreciated.

Best regards,
Nikita

```
import wx

class Frame ( wx.Frame ):
   def __init__( self ):
      wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, None, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos =                wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~   (wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.RESIZE_BORDER) )
      nums = (('1',(0,3)), ('2',(2,3)), ('14', (3,3)), ('15',(4,3)), ('16',(5,3)), ('17',(6,3)), ('18',(7,3)),
        ('3',(1,0)), ('4',(1,1)), ('5',(1,2)), ('6',(1,3)), ('7',(1,4)), ('8',(1,5)), ('9',(1,6)), ('10',(1,7)),
        ('11',(1,8)), ('12',(1,9)), ('13',(1,10)))

      panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
      panel.SetBackgroundColour("green")
      grid = wx.GridBagSizer(2,2)

      for num, pos in nums:
         button = wx.Button(panel, wx.NewId(), label = num)
         grid.Add(button, pos, flag=wx.EXPAND)

      bs2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
      bs2.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND,0)

      panel.SetSizer(bs2)
      panel.Layout()
      self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
      self.mainSizer.Add(panel, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
      self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
      self.Layout()

if __name__=='__main__':
   app=wx.PySimpleApp()
   app.frame = Frame()
   app.frame.Center()
   app.frame.Show(True)
   app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must allow the columns to grow by calling `AddGrowableCol`:

```
  for i in range(11):
      grid.AddGrowableCol(i)
```

Now, they can grow, but they won't shrink beyond their initial size!  So you should also reduce their starting size:

```
  for num, pos in nums:
     button = wx.Button(panel, wx.NewId(), size=(10,-1), label = num)
     #original code was:  button = wx.Button(panel, wx.NewId(), label = num)
     grid.Add(button, pos, flag=wx.EXPAND)
```

Here is the complete listing:

```
import wx

class Frame ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self ):
       wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, None, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos =
                         wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ),
                         style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~   (wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.RESIZE_BORDER) )
       nums = (('1',(0,3)), ('2',(2,3)), ('14', (3,3)), ('15',(4,3)), ('16',(5,3)), ('17',(6,3)), ('18',(7,3)),
         ('3',(1,0)), ('4',(1,1)), ('5',(1,2)), ('6',(1,3)), ('7',(1,4)), ('8',(1,5)), ('9',(1,6)), ('10',(1,7)),
         ('11',(1,8)), ('12',(1,9)), ('13',(1,10)))

       panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)
       panel.SetBackgroundColour("green")
       grid = wx.GridBagSizer(2,2)

       for num, pos in nums:
           button = wx.Button(panel, wx.NewId(), size=(10,-1), label = num)
           grid.Add(button, pos, flag=wx.EXPAND)

       for i in range(11):
           grid.AddGrowableCol(i)

       bs2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
       bs2.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND,0)

       panel.SetSizer(bs2)
       panel.Layout()
       self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
       self.mainSizer.Add(panel, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
       self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
       self.Layout()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    app.frame = Frame()
    app.frame.Center()
    app.frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks! But when using GridSizer, the size of items that are added to the sizer is automatically adjusted to the size of a frame (where you set the sizer). Is it possible to adjust the size of items automatically (not manually)

Comment: That's exactly what my above code achieves.  The 10 is only the minimum horizontal size.